# Select2 - Multi Select Autocompletion - Programmatically population of field

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using the bundled [AUI Select2 Lib](https://aui.atlassian.com/aui/9.1.4/docs/auiselect2.html) in a JIRA 8.13 instance.

What I would like to try is to code an autocompletion field with multiple values. My main components are running so far, but I have some problems while populating the field programmatically via JavaScript.

This my basic setup:

```
   field.auiSelect2(
   {
      multiple: true,
      closeOnSelect: true,
      tokenSeparators: [","],
      placeholder: PLACEHOLDER,
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      formatResult: format,
      initSelection: function (element, callback) {
         callback({id: $(element).val(), text: $(element).val()});
      },
      ajax: {
         url: <...>,
         dataType: 'json',
         data: function (term) {
            return {term: term,};
         },
         results: function (results) {
            return results;
         },
         quietMillis: 250,
         cache: false
      },
   });
```

The field population code is the following:

```
field.val(["A","B","C"]).trigger('change');
```

But this results in a single entry in the input field value **"A,B,C"** which is wrapped within a single gray box instead of multiple boxes - one for each passed value.

[image: single value]

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? I guess it might be related to the `initSelection` parameter.

https://codepen.io/aschuma/pen/rNLRLWL

Comment: There is an error in your population code (missing a `"`), but it seems more like maybe your options themselves are getting populated incorrectly. Perhaps giving a fiddle that reproduced the error would help, because there is nothing inherently wrong with the code you've given.

Comment: You are right, I should have provided a fiddle/codepen. I have updated my question and added a codepen link.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(field).auiSelect2("data", [{id: "A", text: "A"},{id:"B", text: "B"},{id:"C", text: "C"}]);
```

https://codepen.io/aschuma/pen/ExyMNJP

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are using an `<input>` element instead of a `<select>` element. When you call this:

```
field.val(["A","B","C"]).trigger('change');
```

what you are really doing is setting the value of the `<input>` field which operates completely separately from select2. An `<input>` field can only have a single value, so it is likely that jQuery simply calls a standard `.join()` on the array and then sets the value to that. You can verify this is correct by simply opening a console and running:

```
console.log(["A","B","C"].join())
```

which will result in the string **"A,B,C"**. What you might need is a `<select>` element which can support multiple values. Also note that the latest version of [AUI Select2 (9.1.4)](https://aui.atlassian.com/aui/9.1.4/docs/auiselect2.html) uses [select2 version 3.4.5](https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/3.4.5) instead of the latest version ([4.0.13](https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/4.0.13) as of the time of this post).

You could also [set the data on the select2 instance itself](https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays#loading-array-data) like so:

```
$(field).auiSelect2('data', [
  {id: 'A', text: 'A'},
  {id: 'B', text: 'B'},
  {id: 'C', text: 'C'},
]);
```

Comment: Hi Jason, 

thank you for your valuable input!!

Finally I solved the issue by using

   $(field).auiSelect2("data", [{id: "A", text: "A"},{id:"B", text: "B"},{id:"C", text: "C"}]); 

to populate the field. In addition I removed the initSelection stuff in the configuration. This was NOT required to make the codepen running fine. But this was somehow different in JIRA.

Anyway initSelection seems to be a left over of the legacy 3.4.5 implementation. 

I did not replace the input field by select. Seems to work in 4.x too. 

See https://codepen.io/aschuma/pen/ExyMNJP

Comment: Good call, I missed the option of setting the data directly on the select2 instance. I added it to my answer for completeness

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread because we had the same problem. I can confirm that it's also posible using  elements if you use the following code.

```js
   AJS.$('#customfield_14882').auiSelect2(
   {
  multiple: true,
  closeOnSelect: true,
  tokenSeparators: [","],
  placeholder: PlaceHolder,
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  allowClear:true,
  initSelection: function (element, callback) {
     var arr = $(element).val().split(',');
     var res=[]; 
     for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        res[i]={id:arr[i],text:arr[i]};
     }
     callback(res);
  },
  ajax: {
     url: "<url>",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: function (term) {  
       return {term: term};
     },
     results: function (results) {
       return {results:results};
     },
     quietMillis: 250,
     cache: false
    },
   });
```